# Image vs Div with Background-Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, flexbox

Im trying to build some fancy item grid by using bootstrap and flex. Therefore the item image always has to extend to 100% width of available space by keeping the 1:1 ratio.

http://www.bootply.com/kPLGHtA7Kh

I got it to work by using the css background image. But I struggle to make it look the same by using an img-tag. Im running out of ideas, hope you can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "struggle to make it look the same" ... are you referring to the fact that img tag layout is 2 col instead of 3?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS just specify the `width: 100%` on your image and don't touch the height (or set it to `auto` which is the default).

The parent of your image should also have a `position:absolute` or `position:relative` in order for the width to work properly

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/s3spdy5z/

Comment: That is not the problem. The image takes the whole max-width of the .flex-item, which is not supposed to happen. In the background-image example the div does not take max-width but the img-tag does.

I can not figure out why!

Answer (score 0):

I think the images are pushing the width of the boxes to the `max-width` so kind of overriding the `flexbox` settings. With the background images you basically don't have any content inside them so flexbox can calculate the widths and not worry about content. The images are set to 100% but it thinks you want 100% of the max-width therefore the grid doesn't fit anymore.

If you set `width: 33%;` on the `.flex-item` and remove the min and max the grids will look the same.

Comment: but they are not always 33%, if you resize the screen slowly, you can see sometimes there are only 2 items.

Comment: Use a media query to set it to 50% then